# Material lighter than concrete for planters?

Tags: concrete, materials, cement

I'm trying to build several 24"x 24" square planters with each wall 1.5" thick, similar to the following picture.

The issue is that each one of these planters will weigh at least 200 pounds (without soil), and they will be used in a rooftop. This means that five planters will be 1,000 pounds at least, and our rooftop isn't designed for so much weight.

I used concrete because it's cheap (at around $4/60-lb bag) and it's easily manageable.

Two questions:

1) Is there any building material, similar to concrete, that doesn't weigh that much?

2) Is there an easy way to build 24"x 24" pots? I'm sort of a *DYIer*, but I'm a  beginner with all of this.

[image]

Comment: why are you putting planters on the roof? Do they have to be square planters? if so why not wood with a liner inside? if not why not plastic (can be painted/textured many ways)?

Comment: I put them in my rooftop/terrace because it's the only space I have for plants.

Comment: They don't have to be square, but for a DYIer with vey limited skills, the square planters were the _least-hard_ to build.

Comment: All large planters (plastic being the cheapest) are over $35 each. I figured I could build something more unique for much less than that.

Comment: Since you aren't looking for particularly high strength, you could consider mixing a substantial ratio of polystyrene beads (aka "beanbag filler" at your local craft store) into your concrete.

Comment: Why not those strong plastic buckets painted green?

Comment: Have you considered something like Stucco?  A concrete shell around a lighter form?

Comment: I've used screwed together Melamine board for forms where a smooth surface was needed. As @JPhi1618 mentioned, stucco works, too. If you find a plastic planter of about the right size you can wrap some stucco back (wire/fabric mesh) aournd it and slather on the stucco to your taste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concrete is a mix of four things:

- Water
- Portland cement
- Sand
- Gravel

The magic happens between the first two.  When the portland cement gets wet, it has a chemical reaction (which makes heat) that turns it from a powder into stone.

The last two are just filler materials. It improves strength, reduces cost, and greatly reduces the heat of curing, since sand and gravel don't get hot. Without this, the heat would be unmanageable.

**Nowhere is it written you must use sand and gravel**.  They make a variety of alternate filler materials where weight matters. First on my mind: crushed polystyrene.

Obviously if you are replacing sand and gravel with something else, that means you can't use **pre-mix** concrete.  Pre-mix concrete is a bag with the portland cement, sand and gravel *pre-mixed*.  Since you don't want the sand and gravel, this won't do.

For that matter, nowhere is it written you must use Portland cement.  For instance you can also use epoxy or a variety of other plastics (see TAP Plastics' website for quite the variety) -- either thick with a variety of fillers.

Or you can work "thin", with fiberglass as a very thin but structural material. You can also do "thick" fiberglass, where you do a skin of fiberglass over a polystyrene block "core" - the styrene provides form and compressive strength, and the fiberglass provides tensile strength and a strong skin.  Fiberglass boats are built this way.

No matter what you do, you'll need a form and a release agent to get the form to let go of the finished work.

Answer (score 1):

Add vermiculite to the concrete mix. The process is explained here:

[How to make Vermiculite and Contrete Planters](https://www.gardenguides.com/104213-make-cement-vermiculite-planters.html)